# How to not lose Request attributes when making async (asynchronous) from one Rest Service to another

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

Currently I'm facing the following issue:

- Rest service (Implemented using Spring Boot)
- Inside my rest service I need to make an asynchronous call to another rest service.
- I'm using `@Async` into the public method that will perform the async call.
- I'm using Feign Client to make that rest call.
- I'm intercepting the request using a `feign.RequestInterceptor`

Now the problem:

In the current implementation of the `RequestInterceptor` we have

```
  @Override
  public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {    
    /// Getting a NullPointer here as obviously we have changed the from one thread to another 
    /// when the async call was made

    final HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
        .getRequest();

   //some other irrelevant logic for this example....
  }
```

As we move from one thread to the spawned thread, the information is lost.
I'm assuming it has to do with the `threadlocal` and somehow I should pass the information to an `inheritablethreadlocal`.

What should be the approach to be able to pass the ServletRequestAttributes to the spawned thread, without losing the information? (basically I'm interested in be able to preserve headers that came in the original thread).

Comment: But I want to set those headers specific headers( not all the ones that came in the original request, but a subset of them) in the RequestTemplate. So I have to do this when I'm intercepting the request. Which means, that I can't just  pass those headers to the async method, as the async method is basically calling the Feign client, and right there the request is intercepted, the headers filtered and added to the requestTemplate.

Comment: No, just to be able to get headers in the request interceptor, which is basically the request that came from the asynchronous call, which is basically a new thread.